# Solving kinetic energy exercise through electrical work formula instead of voltage formula?

Tags: energy, electricity, work, voltage, homework-and-exercises

While studying electric potential, I run into an issue on exercise 43 of Chapter 24 of Fundamentals of
Physics 8th ed. Vol. 3 (Halliday et al.).

The exercise states the following, paraphrased:
A charged particle (q = 7.5uC) is released from rest at point 60cm on the x axis.
It moves 40cm due to another charged particle (Q) at point 0cm (origin) on the x axis.
The exercise asks what is the kinetic energy of the particle (q) after the displacement,
considering: (a) Q = 20uC and (b) Q = -20uC.

To solve the exercise I used the following:
$E_{kf} = -q * \Delta V$

I arrived at the intended results: (a) Ecf = 0.9 joule and (b) Ecf = 4.5 joule.

My question is:
Is it possible to reach the results by using the electrical work formula $W_e = F_e * ds$
instead? I've tried using it, but I do not get the same results.
Does it require some data not informed by the exercise? Is it applicable to this situation? Am I misinterpreting something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the same result by using the electrical work formula - but note that you need to *integrate* since the force changes with position. That's really all the potential is - it is the integral of force for unit charge. That's why force has the $1/r^2$ relationship while potential has $1/r$ (with appropriate signs and constants...).

Perhaps this is enough. If not, then show how you tried to use the electrical force equation to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks very much, I was calculating the wrong way. But now that I integrate it, the results are the same.